# Hardware reader utility works under IIS Express but not IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web API (2.2) Intranet service at work that encapsulates access to a smart card reader for generating public key signatures. The smart card reader relies on an open-source command line utility (pkcs15-crypt) to perform hardware access and I have no problem getting the service to work while debugging in VS2013 and IIS Express. When I run it on regular IIS, though, the command line utility reports that it cannot find any smart card readers.

I've tried a few different identities for my app pool (including my own domain login) but so far no success. It behaves the same way on both IIS 7.5 on a Windows 7 box and IIS 8 on a Windows 8 machine (64-bit in both cases).

What else might I be missing here? What might be different about IIS Express that lets the utility see the hardware, whereas it isn't working in the context of full-blown IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented with various identities for my IIS app pool, and the ones that worked were

- LocalService
- LocalSystem

Identities that didn't work were:

- NetworkService
- ApplicationPoolIdentity
- My own domain account